# How to make a html link to open in new tab in Python

Tags: python, html

I have,

```
fruits = [ apple, banana, pineapple, oranges] 
htmlfile = open('home-page.html','w')
htmlfile.write("<html>\n")
htmlfile.write("<head>\n")
htmlfile.write("<title> Home </title>\n")
htmlfile.write("</head>\n")
htmlfile.write("<body>\n")
htmlfile.write("<h1> Fruit-properties </h1?\n")
htmlfile.write("<a href = " 'fruit+'.html"> '+fruit+'</a><br>\n")
htmlfile.write("</body>\n")
htmlfile.write("</html>\n")
htmlfile.write.close()
```

I have separate code to create fruit.html for each fruit and can't write here because it is part of big code that I am writing.

so basically everything works fine. but when I click on any link, it is opened in the same browser. Is there any way that I can write in python to open the link in different tab??

I can't make use of `webbrowser` option of python, because it is a linked page to my home-page.

Can somebody help?

Comment: How has this got anything to do with Python?

Comment: And why did someone vote this question up?

Comment: This question is related to python because html is implemented using it. And someone will vote it up because that person found it useful. Very much discouraging administrators you are @jobrsharpe. We look at stackoverflow as a good source of coding help. I certainly doubt what way you judge the posts. In one day you downvoted all my posts and now I can't post questions. Very much sad and discouraging this is.

Comment: Thanks people for voting up. But still I am not allowed to post my questions.

Comment: can somebody help me with this question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/651444/how-to-delete-duplicate-lines-starting-with-specific-word-in-python , I am unable to post on stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `target="_blank"` and modify your link tag to

```
'<a href="' + fruit + '.html" target="_blank">' + fruit + '</a><br>\n'
```

the link will open in a new browser or tab.

**Edit**: As pointed out the behaviour is browser-dependent, but it's the most you can do. As it seems there was a CSS3 proposal for this issue but it was abandoned ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/811708)).

Comment: it is actually opening it in separate window instead of tab

Comment: I guess that's browser-dependent; In my browser (Chrome) it opens up a new tab.

Comment: will this work in IE? webbrowser.get(internet explorer).open(website url), it throws me an error like browser not found. any specific syntax for IE is used in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following property to your `<a>` tag to make the link open up in a separate tab or browser window - `target="_blank"` . So in your above code, it would become -

```
htmlfile.write('<a href = " 'fruit+'.html" target="_blank"> '+fruit+'</a><br>\n')
```

Also, the above line had some problems with quotes, you should open and close with single quotes, since you are using single quotes in the middle for `fruit`.

Comment: it is actually opening it in separate window, instead of tab.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Like adrianus points out, it is browser dependent, it you always want launch the link in a new tab only, you would need to write complex javascripts.

Comment: can I change my webbrowser to IE while popping up the home page itself using webbrowser.get?

Comment: Try this - `webbrowser.get('c:\\program files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe')`

Answer (score 0):

I found that by default it was making use of some other browser to popup the home page. So in my code I made Mozilla-firefox as my default browser and solved the problem.

```
webbrowser.get('firefox').open(website)
```

I tried the same for internet explorer too and it worked.